# How to subtract collections with Comparator interface instead of overriding equals

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I want to compute differences between collections. When using CollectionUtils.subtract() for custom comparison I need to override the object's equals() method. But what if I need to compare collections of objects of the same type but different comparison criterion? What about the Comparator interface, it seems perfectly suited here? AFAIK Comparator is mainly used for sorting. Isn't there a method that uses Comparators for subtracting?

Comment: We _override_ `equals`, not _overwrite_ it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ArrayList, multiple removes can be more expensive than taking a copy.

```
List<Type> list = /* ArrayList */
Set<Type> toRemove = /* HashSet */
List<Type> copy = new ArrayList<Type>(list.size());
for(Type t: list)
  if(!toRemove.contains(t))
    copy.add(t);
list = copy;
```

---

Personally I would use a loop. Its likely to be shorter and clearer.

```
Collection<Type> collection =

for(Iterator<Type> i=collection.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
   if (i.next() is to be removed)
       i.remove();
```

The reason an Iterator is used explicitly is to use the Iterator.remove() which avoids a ConcurrentModificationException.  Another way to avoid it is to use a copy of the collection which might be preferred.

```
for(Type t : new ArrayList<Type>(collection))
   if (t is to be removed)
       collection.remove(t);
```

This doesn't perform as well but may perform well enough.

Comment: This might give an exception as you modify the collection while looping over it, so you have to make a copy

Comment: Not if you use `Iterator.remove()`.  If you modify the collection in another thread you can get an exception whether you copy it or not.

Comment: @Frank Meulenaar, I have included the alternative you suggested, though either will work.

Comment: The problem here is that it's too time consuming. I subtract from lists that contains > 20.000 items each.

Comment: If you have a large ArrayList, removing objects is going to expensive. It may be faster to create a copy of the elements you want to keep and replace the original.

Comment: With a copy as LinkedList it computes way faster than with ArrayList. The loss of time compared to the TreeSet approach is acceptable considering that equals() isn't used anymore

Answer (score 4):

```
static <Type> Collection<Type> subtract(Collection<Type> a, Collection<Type> b, Comparator<Type> c) {
    Set<Type> subtrahend = new TreeSet<Type>(c);
    subtrahend.addAll(b);
    Collection<Type> result = new ArrayList<Type>();
    for (Type item: a) {
        if (!subtrahend.contains(item)) result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `subtrahent` tree-set is not necessary, but will improve performance for large `b`.

Comment: The Comparator here is only used for sorting the collection items. removeAll() again uses the equals method of the type, not any logic provided by the Comparator

Comment: Are you sure? TreeSet internally uses a TreeMap, where `remove()` relies on `getEntry()`, which uses the comparator.

Comment: It seems that `TreeSet`s whose comparators are not agreeable with equality `equals()` run into problems with `removeAll()`. Please have a look [here](http://lingpipe-blog.com/category/java/page/5/).

Comment: Oh my... TreeSet really should override `removeAll()` then. I updated my answer